# Loop through form fields with JQuery using .submit() event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little problem with form submission with jquery. I've submitted a lot of forms with it in the past but I was just thinking, how can I use the event handler .submit() to submit a form and it's elements without callin the forms ID. The problem is that I can't seem to be able to chain elements with $(this) (it's possible using .children() but I just want to use .each() through the input fields).

Here is a code snippet:

```
$('.editTimeLink').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.get('<?php echo $config["httpRoot"]; ?>/ajax.php?ajax=1&sec=time&a=edit&id=' + id, {}, function (data) {
        if (data.returnCode == 1) {
            $('#timeBox_' + id).html(data.data);
            $('#timeBox_' + id + ' form').bind('submit', function () {
                //$(this).$(':input').each(function () {
                //$(this).(':input').each(function () {
                $(this).each(':input', function () {
                    alert("adsf");
                });

                return false;
            });
        } else if (data.returnCode == 0) {
            alert(data.data);
        }
    }, 'json');

    return false;
});
```

Like you can see I'm trying to alert the string "asdf" for each input element in the form "this".

You can see where the 2 lines are commented out what I have been trying to manage. The line that isn't commented out doesn't work neither. I know how I can fix this, for instance pass the form selectors name to the lambda function but I was just thinking if there's a more "clean" way to do this?

Thanks in advance.
Kristinn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use `children()`? You can still use `each()`.

```
$(this).children(':input').each(...);
```

However, this does not work:

```
$(this).each(':input', function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

Because `each()` only takes one argument, a callback ([doc here](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each#callback)).

By the way: using a JS debugger, e.g., [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1843), is a good idea to find out why stuff is not working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I did know about that but it's nice to get this all sorted out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

.children() selects immediate children, so if you have a table or other markup in your form you'll want to use .find()

```
$(this).find(':input').each(function(i){
    console.log($(this).val()); //$(this) now contains the current form field in the loop
});
```